# The "Ask question" button is rather obscure/hidden

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we make the “ask question” button stand out more?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/501/can-we-make-the-ask-question-button-stand-out-more)

I've used stackoverflow, photo.stackexchange.com and others, but I couldn't find the "ask question" button on askubuntu.com.  After 30s I pulled up stackoverflow.com, found where it has the button, then found it on askubuntu.com

The button blends into the background, I'd suggest we make it stand out!