# Isn't the "Ask question" button on this website a bit inconspicuous?

Tags: discussion, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please make the “Ask Question” button on AskUbuntu more prominent](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3490/please-make-the-ask-question-button-on-askubuntu-more-prominent)

It took me 3 minutes to find the damn "Ask question" button on this website and it's all because it's so white you can barely notice it. There also is barely any contrast around there.

Comment: It's white on purple with drop shadows.. how is that not visible.

Comment: *at the least* - even change the font color! EDIT: it's a sprite image!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. We've talked about it before:

- [Can we make the "ask question" button stand out more?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/501/can-we-make-the-ask-question-button-stand-out-more/502#502)
- [Giving feedback on the design](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/409/giving-feedback-on-the-design/505#505)
- [Please make the "Ask Question" button on AskUbuntu more prominent](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3490/please-make-the-ask-question-button-on-askubuntu-more-prominent)

We talk and talk and talk. We've been talking about this for two years and we always come to to same conclusion: the ask question link gives a *relatively* awful user experience. I think there's unity in everybody's mind that we want it changing.

But nobody having these discussions has the power to edit the design directly. It's slightly annoying to be ignored so thoroughly by our usually-benevolent overlords but I guess on the scale of things, the link is just a link. People seem to find it eventually.

Comment: Makes a terrible first hand experience just as with all things Linux...
Isn't there a web developer e-mail address around here somewhere?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/other